# rotating variable in ddply

Tags: r, variables, dataframe, plyr

I am trying to get means from a column in a data frame based on a unique value. So trying to get mean of column b and column c in this exampled based on the unique values in column a. I thought the .(a) would make it calculate by unique value in a (it gives the unique values of a) but it just gives a mean for the whole column b or c.

```
df2<-data.frame(a=seq(1:5),b=c(1:10), c=c(11:20))    
simVars <- c("b", "c")
for ( var in simVars ){
print(var)

dat = ddply(df2, .(a), summarize, mean_val = mean(df2[[var]])) ## my script
assign(var, dat)

}
c

a mean_val
1     15.5
2     15.5
3     15.5
4     15.5
5     15.5
```

How can I have it take an average for the column based on the unique value from column a?

thanks

Comment: Just don't re-specify the data frame: `mean_val = mean(var)`, not `mean_val = mean(df2[[var]])`.

Comment: switching it to mean_val = mean(var) doesn't work, I had tried that before. It returns error In mean.default(var) : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.

Comment: The desired output is that table above, except the mean_val column is wrong. It is taking a mean for all values in the c column, but what it is supposed to be doing is taking a mean for c column values that a=1, mean for c column values where a=2, mean for c columnvalues where a=3, etc.                                       I want this: dat = ddply(df2, .(a), summarize, mean_val = mean(c)) but instead of having mean(c), have mean(var) so that it rotates the variable, but works because mean(var) does not

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop. Just calculate the means of `b` and `c` within a single call to `ddply` and the means will be calculated separately for each value of `a`. And, as @Gregor said, you don't need to re-specify the data frame name inside `mean()`:

```
ddply(df2, .(a), summarise, 
      mean_b=mean(b),
      mean_c=mean(c))

  a mean_b mean_c
1 1    3.5   13.5
2 2    4.5   14.5
3 3    5.5   15.5
4 4    6.5   16.5
5 5    7.5   17.5
```

**UPDATE:** To get separate data frames for each column of means:

```
# Add a few additional columns to the data frame
df2 = data.frame(a=seq(1:5),b=c(1:10), c=c(11:20), d=c(21:30), e=c(31:40))   

# New data frame with means by each level of column a
library(dplyr)
dfmeans = df2 %>%
  group_by(a) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(mean))

# Separate each column of means into a separate data frame and store it in a list:
means.list = lapply(names(dfmeans)[-1], function(x) {
  cbind(dfmeans[,"a"], dfmeans[,x])
})

means.list

[[1]]
  a   b
1 1 3.5
2 2 4.5
3 3 5.5
4 4 6.5
5 5 7.5

[[2]]
  a    c
1 1 13.5
2 2 14.5
3 3 15.5
4 4 16.5
5 5 17.5

[[3]]
  a    d
1 1 23.5
2 2 24.5
3 3 25.5
4 4 26.5
5 5 27.5

[[4]]
  a    e
1 1 33.5
2 2 34.5
3 3 35.5
4 4 36.5
5 5 37.5
```

Comment: My real work has 8 variables, and I need them in different data frames. So I am trying to avoid doing ab<- ddply(df2, .(a), summarize, mean_b=mean(b)), ac<- ddply(df2, .(a), summarize, mean_b=mean(c)), ad<- ddply(df2, .(a), summarize, mean_b=mean(d)), etc. Thus why I have the for loop to go through my variables and create the individual data frames. And data.f<- ddply(df2, .(a), summarize, mean_b=mean(var)) does not work. It cannot pull in the variable there

Comment: Great, that helps a lot. But what are the names of these data frames, and how can I access them and bring them up later? Thanks!

Comment: If the list is called `means.list`, then, for example, to get the second data frame in the list you would do `means.list[[2]]`. You can also give the list elements more descriptive names. For example, `names(means.list) = names(dfmeans[2:5])`. Then, to refer to the data frame containing the means of column `e`, you would do `means.list[["e"]]`.

Comment: Last question. If my original data frame has 16 columns and I only want the mean on 8 of them, instead of summarise_each(funs(mean)) to get mean for every column, how can I do it for just the 8 I want?

Comment: Then you just need to add a `select` statement in the `dplyr` function chain to select the columns you want. For example, if you want means of columns 2 through 9 of your data frame, then do: `df2 %>% group_by(a) %>% select(2:9) %>% ...`